# How do I format my email address in field of a table to take two lines

Tags: vertical-alignment

I currently use the code:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{10mm} @{\hskip 2.5mm}p{5cm}}
    {\Huge \textnormal{\faEnvelopeO}} &
    {\tiny firstname.lastname@}\\
    &{\tiny gmail.com}  \\
    {\Huge \textnormal{\faPhoneSquare}} & 0176-1234567\\
\end{tabular}
```

That produces the image:

[image]

Given that this looks bad, so I want to have both lines of the email address next to the email icon. At best it would also have mailto formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost easier to set the `\faEnvelopeO` separate from the `tabular`, so you can change their `align`ment to the vertical `c`entre independently:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{valign = c}{\resizebox{!}{2\baselineskip}{\faEnvelopeO}}%
\hspace{2.5mm}%
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l }
  firstname.lastname@ \\
  gmail.com
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`tabular`s are vertically centred by default.

Note the email address won't be complete and therefore not be properly clickable.

Comment: Thanks, but I do need the table because I have multiple entries in my actual CV.

Comment: @Christian: That doesn't make much of a difference in the approach. See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/uVdt80fa) for how you can use my approach inside a `tabular`.