# How do I get \documentclass{memoir} compatible with \usepackage{setspace}?

Tags: memoir, setspace

I want to use the package setspace in my document which has the class memoir. Unfortunately, as long as the document class is that way, the package doesn't work. I want to reduce linespacing. Is there a way to get  it working in that document class? Otherwise is there another way to reduce linespacing?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

one\\
{\setstretch{0.5}
two\\
three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't really want to halve the baseline space do you? (it will make it impossible to fit in the letters??)

Comment: I have certain sections of my document where the standard spacing in too much. It might be that 0.75 is better but I need `setspace` or something similar.

Comment: anything less than about 95% and tex will not be able to maintain a consistent linespacing however you don't need any package standard latex has `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{0.95}` if you really must.

Comment: `memoir` has its own methods for changing the line spacing; but using such a thing as `\linespread{0.5}\selectfont` (which is essentially what you'd like to do) is a sure recipe for uneven typesetting. My impression is that you're asking an XY-question: can you explain what's the *real* problem?

Comment: @egreg : For space reasons the email address in my document has to take two lines. I asked for that at [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414154/239). It would look nicer if the lines of the email address would be closer together.

Comment: Why not ``\\[-1ex]`` or whatever dimension you need?

Comment: As mentioned `memoir` has similar functionality, we even took some code from `setspace` but made it a little different because `setspace` often caused LaTeX to give some warnings, our implementation did not.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://greengabbro.net/2009/02/15/line-spacing-with-the-latex-memoir-class-why-doesnt-setspacesty-work/), simply add

```
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

in your preamble. Make sure `DisemulatePackage` comes before `usepackage`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you! I hope it's helpful.